# Why developers set OkHttp to Retrofit if Retrofit already uses OkHttp internally

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

I know, that Retrofit uses OkHttp internally.
But, I can see that some developers provided applying of approach as bellow

```
return new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT)
        .client(getClient()) // we can add OkHttpClient client there
```

So, can someone clarify why this needed?

I have heard that this can be helpful for testing, when we can apply custom Interceptor during mocking of HTTP requests

Comment: Let say you have multiple instance of Retrofit, will u also use multiple instance of OkHttp?

Answer (score 11):

Retrofit does get an instance of OkHttp by itself but does not perform any customization of the `OkHttpClient`. In a lot of cases, you might need to customize you client to take advantage of the flexibility of OkHttp. Take a look at what you can do [in this JavaDoc](http://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/). You can see that you can do a lot of things like set your own timeout, your own DNS, your own custom cache (could come in handy in graphics intensive apps), your own proxy, limit protocols based on user device (a country might block HTTPS so you want to be able to fall back to HTTP in this case as quickly as possible) and many more.

EDIT:
In most usage cases this might not be needed such as in a simple API call to a REST API endpoint. But in some cases, such as video streaming, VPN or proxy services, or whatever case that requires you to customize your app to geographical regions or different network connections you could benefit from this. Other examples that come to mind are some messaging or social apps that are blocked by certain countries. Even an app like Spotify or YouTube. When the user is connected through WiFi you want to route them to your high speed server through a high speed protocol (say UDP). But if the user is connected via 3G you want to route them to a different server and using TCP protocol to ensure quality.

Answer (score 6):

You should explicitly provide an `OkHttp` instance to `Retrofit`, otherwise `Retrofit` would implicitly perform `.client(new OkHttpClient())`, thus you'd not get a lot of *smart things*, e.g. disk caching, connection pooling.

See how Jake Wharton clarifies the case in [*"Making Retrofit Work For You"* talk](https://youtu.be/t34AQlblSeE?t=500).

**Edit**

Above mentioned case makes sense if you have multiple retrofit instances.

Comment: "thus you'd not get a lot of smart things" thus how? Why do you not get these things if you don't provide a client manually?

Comment: @Tim Castelijns, I'll rephrase your question to "why do you get these smart things if you provide a client manually?" Because now your retrofit instances would share the same okhttp client. Otherwise they use separate instances of okHttp client. See the video for more information.

Comment: You should include that in the answer. Many people including myself use a single Retrofit instance, in which case it doesn't matter

Comment: Yes, if you use single retrofit - it doesn't matter, you are absolutely correct. But what's the reasoning behind "you shouldn't put that in the answer"?

Comment: I don't know the reasoning behind something I didn't say

Comment: @TimCastelijns, now I see. Sorry for confusion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to described answers, I would like to provide one more example.
Applying of the custom OkHttp can be super helpful during testing of network requests.

You can make two OkHttpClient clients.
One in prod flavor, other in mock flavor.

OkHttpClient for prod flavor should work as expected.
OkHttpClient for mock flavor should use custom Interceptor.
This custom Interceptor can be used for analysis of requests to a server and applying of your predefined responses from your assets folder.
This is the pretty elegant way to mock work with a server.